# Advantages of Perl over shell scripting for text file processing

Tags: perl, shell

I'm setting up a test environment to test a program. This environment includes lots of text files that are given as input, and again the expected behaviour of the program is documented in another set of text files. I wanted to run the program with all the input files sequentially and compare the output generated with the reference files.
Since i have a choice over languages that i can use(shell or perl), i wanted to know what are the advantages / strengths of perl language.

Answer (score 7):

Perl has at least the following advantages over just about any shell...

- Portability

  - Works on Windows
  - Even on Unix the same shell command can behave very differently from system to system
- A [debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)
- A [wide selection of libraries](https://metacpan.org/)
- Better structures such as [object-oriented](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) and functional programming
- Better ways to document with [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)
- Better testing facilities such as [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) and [700+ other test libraries](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Test)
- Better [packaging of projects](http://dzil.org/) for distribution

Most dynamic languages (Perl, Python, Ruby...) share these advantages.

Comment: I am not sure if I would add Perl's *object orientation* and the alleged 700+ test libraries as an advantage. But Portability and the vast number of libraries sure make perl my currently preferred scripting language. +1.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Out-of-the-box Perl OO stinks. The OO link is to Moose, likely not what you probably think of as Perl OO.

Comment: The [700+ test libraries](http://nopaste.info/1f14f0cabd.html) are not alleged. Trust me, [I have to keep them working](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Builder).

Comment: Re:OO I see now... I was not following the link you posted. I   must admit I have never looked into Moose.

Answer (score 5):

Since Schwern listed quite some advantages, I'm only left with pointing the one weakness that continues bugging me.

Calling into other programs is a lot more complicated in Perl than in shell. There are a number of cornercases that you need to handle where shell mostly just does the right thing.

My personal rule of thumb is to use shell script when the task is mostly about calling other programs, and Perl when I'm working on data. If both are needed, I'd probably go with a shell script that calls into Perl for data munging, although it might turn out to be a full Perl script if only few external commands are issued.

Comment: Writing a Perl script that processes STDIN and outputs to STDOUT allows you to use constructs like `unix_command | perl_script | other_unix_command > output_file`

Comment: That's what I meant with mixing Perl and sh.

Comment: I agree completely. However, have a look at [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Run) and [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::All) for better ways to do it than the standard system and backticks.

Comment: Schwern: Two very impressive modules you mentioned there.